# Can HTC Desire 530 be rooted?

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

I have a HTC Desire 530, Android 6.0.1, can it be rooted? I want to make sure before I root it with Kingroot.

I've tried looking over the web for indexes of allowed devices, and I haven't seen it, but I'm not too sure about those lists as well.

So I'm just going to ask here, can this phone be safely rooted or not?

Comment: KingRoot, iRoot, FramaRoot, etc seem not to work on Android 6.0.1. Try the PC version of Kingo Root (not tested though).

Comment: There is a forum for your phone model at XDA Developers: http://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-530

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand anything, and it says that unlocking the bootloader wipes my phone. I don't want that. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Yes unlocking the bootloader always wipe all data. You can't get root access without unlocking the bootloader. Just make a backup of your data.

Comment: If i use Kingo Root is all my data going to be gone? It seems to support my device, it tells me HTC Desire 530 and a "ROOT" button. Just in case I'm making a full backup using the SDK adb.exe . But still, I want to know.

Comment: I never experienced that while rooting with Kingo root or any one-click root software. But you should backup your data. Just for precaution.

Comment: My phone was successfully rooted. It did wipe all data, but I did a backup. Re-installing some apps now. It's awesome. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, HTC Desire 530 can be rooted. Check out:

http://www.androidinfotech.com/2016/12/root-htc-desire-530-marshmallow-twrp.html

https://rootthat.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-root-htc-desire-530.html

The PC version of Kingo Root works as well.